# XP Client for NFS failure dialog on startup, but drive mapping works

Tags: windows, nfs

I'm mounting an NFS share to some windows machines using the tools that come in the Services for UNIX Administration toolkit.

I've set up the User Name Mapping service to use local passwd and group files. I had to manually start the User Name Mapping service, and then created an 'advanced map' from the XP machine's user to a uid that exists in on my NFS server, like so:

- Windows User: Matt Bennett
- UNIX Domain: PCNFS
- UNIX User: mattbennett
- UID: 10250
- Primary: *

I can map a network drive without any issues, and it correctly identifies the UID and GID to use, but when I reboot I get this message:

"An error occurred while connecting to the NFS server. Make sure that the Client for NFS service has started. If the problem persists make sure Client for NFS service can communicate with User Name Mapping or PCNFS server."

After dismissing the dialog, the machine finishes booting and the network drive is there in My Computer with the title "Disconnected Network Drive", but I can open it I can see the network share without a problem, and then it drops the 'disconnected' from its title.

It seems like the services are starting in the wrong order or something, so the first attempt to connect fails but subsequent ones work as expected. There don't seem to be any symptoms apart from the dialog box, but obviously something's not quite right.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,
Matt.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question I ran into the same problem some time ago. Windows is attempting to restore the mapped network drives before they unix services are ready. You can get rid of the error message but it will show up as a disconnected network drive until you double click on it. This has been tested on Windows XP SP3 Pro.

You can create a new dword in regedit

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\

add a new key DWORD named

RestoreConnection

set it to 0

This will suppress the message as the drive won't attempt to reconnect before the unix services have been loaded. So far I haven't been able to find anything out about the "firing order" but this does remove the message so the system will continue to load. For me this was functional enough to move on to the other projects.

I did a quick tutorial on setting up NFS clients as I couldn't find anything about this online.
http://www.hilands.com/os-windows-nfsclient.html